# How to use a different label (variable name) in each iteration (variable)?

Tags: r, bar-chart, apply, var, lapply

I have a dataframe *data* with 40 variables and I have a function *func* which draws a barplot among other things.

```
func <- function(var, arg1, arg2){
  # ...
  barplot(table(arg1, arg2)[2,], 
          ylab = "Frequency",
          xlab = names(var))
  # ...
}
```

I want to apply this function to my dataframe and get a barplot for each one of the 40 variables, using the name of each variable like **xlab** of each barplot. I've used lapply to do this but I'm not be able to show the name of each variable as **xlab**.

```
lapply(data, func, arg1, arg2))
```

Comment: Don't `lapply` over `data` but over `names(data)`.

Comment: @Axeman Although I haven't shown that, in my function I need also data information besides of the variables names, so if I `lapply` over `names(data)` I think I can't use `data` information.

Comment: Use `subs <- data[[arg]]` or similar at the top of your function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `mapply`, which can be used to loop over multiple objects where the indices line up between the objects.

```
func <- function(x, name) plot(x, main = name)

mapply(FUN = func, x = iris, name = names(iris))
```